# Is there a Wikipedia API?

Tags: api, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

On my Wikipedia user page, I run a Wikipedia script that displays my statistics (number of pages edited, number of new pages, monthly activity, etc.).

I'd like to put this information on my blog.

Is there an API that would allow me to do something like this?

Comment: Check out [Extract the first paragraph from a Wikipedia article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460921/extract-the-first-paragraph-from-a-wikipedia-article-python).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

MediaWiki's [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) is running on Wikipedia ([docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)). You can also use the [Special:Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export) feature to dump data and parse it yourself.

[More information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#APIs_for_bots).

Answer (score 18):

Wikipedia is built on MediaWiki, and here's the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

Answer (score 15):

If you want to extract structured data from Wikipedia, you may consider using DbPedia http://dbpedia.org/

It provides means to query data using given criteria using SPARQL and returns data from parsed Wikipedia infobox templates

Here is a quick example how it could be done in .NET http://www.kozlenko.info/blog/2010/07/20/executing-sparql-query-on-wikipedia-in-net/

There are some SPARQL libraries available for multiple platforms to make queries easier

Answer (score 9):

JWPL - Java-based Wikipedia Library -- An application programming interface for Wikipedia

http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/

Answer (score 5):

Here are 2 from infochimps.com:

http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/wikipedia-articles-abstract-search

http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/wikipedia-articles-title-autocomplete