# Wikipedia API library for PHP

Tags: php, api, wikipedia

Is there a Wikipedia API library for PHP, especially for the CodeIgniter framework? The Wikipedia API documentation is long and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a whole bunch of PHP wrappers for the API:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#PHP

Answer (score 1):

There is an extremely comprehensive API for Wikipedia, and it has been covered before on stackoverflow: [How to use wikipedia api if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964454/how-to-use-wikipedia-api-if-it-exists)

As for the question about a class/library specifically to leverage the API for CodeIgniter, there is none to my knowledge.

However with that said there is very little need for any sort of libraries to leverage the API as you can use built in functions such as [`http_build_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) to make API requests and the request can be returned in any format you desire:

> json, jsonfm, php, phpfm, wddx,
> wddxfm, xml, xmlfm, yaml, yamlfm,
> rawfm, txt, txtfm, dbg, dbgfm