# How to get results from the Wikipedia API with PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, wikipedia-api

I'm probably not supposed to use file_get_contents() What should I use? I'd like to keep it simple.

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Your_Highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: You can do it with file_get_contents, but if you like it simple, use cURL instead, because you need to handle cookies as described in the [API documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login). Both the PHP native and the cURL ways will let you, but it's much simpler in cURL.

Comment: Better than cURL is HTTP_Request2 you can download it via Pear it's a much nicer experience as it is a proper OO library

Comment: @netcoder, you need to handle cookies only if you want to log in. It's no necessary only for accessing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you are running into here is related to the MW API's [User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) - you must supply a `User-Agent` header, and that header must supply some means of contacting you.

You can do this with `file_get_contents()` with a [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'user_agent' => 'MyBot/1.0 (http://www.mysite.com/)'
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Your_Highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0';
var_dump(file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context));
```

Having said that, it might be considered more "standard" to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), and this will certainly give you more control:

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Your_Highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MyBot/1.0 (http://www.mysite.com/)');

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$result) {
  exit('cURL Error: '.curl_error($ch));
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Both the explicit answer to the question and the "right way to do it". Well answered sir.

Comment: The URL has to start with https:// instead of http:// for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` Should work.

```
file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content')
```

This was previously discussed on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964454/how-to-use-wikipedia-api-if-it-exists)

Also, some nice looking code samples [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160808111352/http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)

Comment: Well it would be nice if file_get_contents just worked, it seems to be more complicated than I thought

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are really receiving is

> Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.

This means that you should provide additional details about yourself when using the API. Your usage of file_get_contents does send the required User-Agent.

Here is a working example in curl that identifies itself as a Test for this question:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Your_Highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Testing for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956331/how-to-get-results-from-the-wikipedia-api-with-php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

They themselves say in their API documentation:

> Use any programming language to make an HTTP GET request for that URL

You need to get the URL right, thefollowing worksfor me :
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

you are not specifying the output format as far as I can notice right now!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Your_Highness&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0

Your URL works after adding output format...