# Getting data from wikisource.org site

Tags: php, wikimedia

I am trying to get postal codes from this site:

http://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Lista_kod%C3%B3w_pocztowych_w_Polsce

My code is simple:

```
 <?php
    $postalCode = $_GET['code'];

    $httpAddr = 'http://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Lista_kod%C3%B3w_pocztowych_w_Polsce/Okr%C4%99g_'.$postalCode[0].'_'.$postalCode[0].$postalCode[1].'-xxx';

    file_get_contents($httpAddr);
    ?>
```

But when i set $postalCode to 03-000 (also 01-000, 05-000, but for 07-000, 61-000, 62-000 is working) i am reciving error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://pl.wikisource.org/wiki/Lista_kod%C3%B3w_pocztowych_w_Polsce/Okr%C4%99g_0_03-xxx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/ofix/test.php on line 5
```

Page address is correct, you can copy and past it in your web browser and it works.
Any ideas?

Comment: The webserver is probably blocking it for certain user-agents. Entering the same URL into your web browser is not proof of much.

Comment: wouldn't that just be a one off job, you don't need to scrape that data repeatedly do you ?

Comment: But it always works for codes like 02-000, and never works for codes with 01 prefix for ex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lightness Races in Orbit suspected, it does seem that the webserver is blocking PHP's request.

Using [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of `file_get_contents()` reveals the details:

> `HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden`
>   Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.

A web browser sends a valid User-Agent header in its request, which is why the page loads OK in your browser but not in PHP.

In my tests loading this URL in PHP, sometimes it succeeds with an HTTP status code of 200, other times it fails with 403.  Notice that the error message says scripts **may** be blocked (ie. sometimes they may not be blocked).

**Edit**

See this question for more info: [How to get results from the Wikipedia API with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956331/how-to-get-results-from-the-wikipedia-api-with-php)

Comment: So i set my own user_agent, and now it works perfect. Thank you.