# Is there an API for WikiTravel?

Tags: api, mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-api

Is there an API for WikiTravel data? Is it same as the MediaWiki Api? if any one knows any tutorial or "how to" documentation please let me know.

Comment: Essentially a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964454/how-to-use-wikipedia-api-if-it-exists?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formerly you could find it here:

> [WikiTravel API](http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php)

<s>I hope it will help you, you can change the letters (en) if you want it in another language.</s>

Comment: Note that Wikitravel is running an ancient version of MediaWiki (1.11.2), so great big slabs of API functionality, including anything to do with editing, are not available.

Answer (score 8):

WikiTravel has just been forked as an official [WikiMedia](http://www.wikimedia.org/) project (the organization behind Wikipedia) called "[WikiVoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org)", which runs on pretty much the same version of MediaWiki as Wikipedia and the other projects.

**[WikiVoyage API](http://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php)**, the raw API access.

**[WikiVoyage APISandbox](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox)**, human friendly form to query the API.

Though the API is self-documenting, there is much better [documentation hosted on the MediaWiki wiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page).