# Scraping information from wikipedia

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, wikipedia, yql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)
>   [How to use wikipedia api if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964454/how-to-use-wikipedia-api-if-it-exists)

I'm using YQL to get information from Wikipedia and store it in my private Database. For example I'm scraping [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajinikanth_filmography) page. I need all the film names from the page. 
I'm using this code:

HTML:

```
$.YQL("select * from html where url='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajinikanth_filmography' and xpath='/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/table'", function (data) {
            var str = data.query.results.table.tr;
            console.log(str);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "db.php",
                data: {
                    sendingStr: str
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP:

```
$recv = $_POST['sendingStr'];
$arraySize = count($recv);
for ($i=1; $i < $arraySize; $i++) {
    foreach ($recv[$i]["td"][1] as $value) {
        foreach ($value as $val) {
            if(strlen($val["content"]) >= 3)
            {

                echo $val["content"] . "\n";

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my problem- If you notice in the page, each row in the table has several rowspans. But when I scrap it, I'm getting only first value from each row. What should I change in my code so that I get all values?

Comment: why do you scrape Wikipedia when you can use their API?

Comment: why do you use YQL when you can parse HTML with PHP easily?

Comment: I'm more comfortable with YQL than HTML parsing and I don't have the time to read their documentation and master their API. I've got the whole code but i'm stuck with this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have a look at [DbPedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) - they do all the [complex] scraping for you and present you structured data