# Get data from wikipedia related to keyword submited through form

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a scenario in which a user enters keyword in a text-field. I want to get the related data to that keyword that is present for that submitted keyword on Wikipedia.
How can I achieve this?

```
<form method=POST action=someaction>  
    <input type=text value=enter keyword />  
</form>
```

Comment: Should add more code : what have you tried? What part exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: the main point is i want to get the related data to the keyword submitted by front end user from wikipedia and i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Ok, so what you are asking for is how to programatically find the content on wikipedia for a particular keyword?

Comment: You can check [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

Comment: There's an API available for Wikipedia:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use wikipedia api if it exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964454/how-to-use-wikipedia-api-if-it-exists)

Comment: Dear All i am new to the stackoverflow and i haven,t done a proper homework before asking questions on this site. so its a kind request to all of you who put a ban on me by asking a question to please remove this ban. Next time i will ask questions with proper homework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you're after is page/web/data scraping. This method allows you to parse data (text/images) from an other website onto your own website. As far as I know, cURL is one of the most known (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I think there might be an REST API for wikipedia, but I'm not quite sure (did not searched very long).

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if there is one since Wikipedia is so large.

Comment: yes i know curl but the point is how i filter the data return by curl