# How to strip all tags from wikipedia pages or make page more readable

Tags: c#, php, firefox, wikipedia

I want to strip all   tags, remove the [show][Hide] stuffs from wikipedia, or is there some website that makes pages in more readable format.

Please I am aware of the Wikipedia printable version, but I don't need any tags in that, as I have some other use. So please answer the original question only, about any website or webservice or code snippets in php/C# to remove the tags from a webpages.

Also like when I copy some list from firefox it replaces `<li>` with the *, is it possible to set something in firefox to return some other non readable character like some kind of

dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an HTML parser, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (Python) or [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for example. Or you could try using an XML parser.

Comment: I think the simple HTML DOM looks the best, easy and extensible.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by taking a look at the [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

Comment: looks cool, Is there something in C# or some sort of webservice too, as I don't want to direct each page request to my webservers.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to strip all tags, remove the
>   [show][Hide] stuffs from wikipedia, or
>   is there some website that makes pages
>   in more readable format.

You should take a look at DBpedia, Wikipedia, but just the data.

http://dbpedia.org/About

Comment: doesn't look the right thing, its more like semantic webpage, it just have the heading and the links and meta info about the articles. I don't need the metainfo or semantic info, I need a very simple webpage that is similar to text file without much tags except image, paragraphs, etc.

Answer (score -1):

What about htmlagilitypack

[htmlagilitypackt](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

Similar thread available in stackoverflow

[Is there a Wikipedia API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api)

Try this function.

```
Dim pattern As String = "<(.|\n)*?>"
Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strHtmlString, pattern, String.Empty).Trim()
```

Comment: Bad choice, regex is not used for HTML parsing. There are lot of question and internet articles for details. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html

Comment: that would create another problem in its own, how to create a webpage using the XML, then I have to write even bigger code to generate the html from the parsed XML