# How to analyse Wikipedia article's data base with R?

Tags: sql, mysql, r, database, wikipedia

This is a "big" question, that I don't know how to start, so I hope some of you can give me a direction.  And if this is not a "good" question, I will close the thread with an apology.

I wish to go through the database of Wikipedia (let's say the English one), and do statistics.  For example, I am interested in how many active editors (which should be defined) Wikipedia had at each point of time (let's say in the last 2 years).

I don't know how to build such a database, how to access it, how to know which types of data it has and so on.  So my questions are:

1. What tools do I need for this (besides basic R) ? MySQL on my computer? RODBC database connection?
2. How do you start planning for such a project?

Comment: Does the wikipedia "database" come as a database dump?

Comment: Hi seem, it would appear so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to start here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Which will take you to here:
http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20100312/

And the file you probably want is:

```
# 2010-03-17 04:33:50 done Log events to all pages.
    * This contains the log of actions performed on pages.
    * pages-logging.xml.gz 1.0 GB
```

http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20100312/enwiki-20100312-pages-logging.xml.gz

You'll then import the xml into MySQL. Generating a histogram of users per day, week, year, etc. won't require R. You'll be able to do that with a single MySQL query. Something like:

```
select DAYOFYEAR(wiki_edit_timestamp), count(*)
from page_logs
group by DAYOFYEAR(wiki_edit_timestamp)
order by DAYOFYEAR(wiki_edit_timestamp);
```

etc.

(I'm not sure what their actual schema is, but it'll be something like that.)

You'll run into issues, no doubt, but you'll learn a lot too. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Roger for the head start!  So now my next steps are how to setup the MySQL, and then how to import this in. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You could

- work with the [wikipedia database dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download), as already mentioned
- work with the [live mediawiki API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api), see [this minimal example at Rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code/Rank_languages_by_popularity#R) or [my unfinished approach with a S3 class](http://r-forge.r-project.org/plugins/scmsvn/viewcvs.php/pkg/wzd/R/mediawiki.R?rev=11&root=wzd&view=markup) or [this package by Peter Konings](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/wikirobot/)
- work with [dbpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets), an effort to extract knowledge from wikipedia into a knowledge base. They offer an [online sparql access](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess) I don't know much about, and also datasets as [n-triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Triples) for download. See [this python script](http://www.koders.com/python/fid0322478CADF5D83DC0B6FAA963681CC7A5B1FB34.aspx?s=cheese) which might be a starting point for an R script. This approach might be useful to access the content stored in the wikipedia (such as the infoboxes) but I am not sure if information on contributors to the wikipedia is available.

Answer (score 2):

Try [WikiXRay](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/WikiXRay) (Python/R) and [zotero](https://www.zotero.org/groups/cpov).