# Integrating Wikipedia in desktop application

Tags: gtk

Is there a way that I can integrate Wikipedia in my GTK application. like when I type some word in search entry the data related to that word in Wikipedia should be displayed on my application.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api