# Is there a Wikipedia API which allows you to search and load articles?

Tags: c#, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Wikipedia API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api)

Is there a Wikipedia API which will allow me to search Wikipedia and load the the article?

And are there any examples of using it in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API)