# Wikipedia: How to get the people with a barn start award holder and the awardee?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

For my socialigy project, I need to get wikipedia barn star award holders, awardee and the date awarded.

I see that awards are normally given added to user profiles by awardee by adding a tag.

I have a list of 359 users, and want to know the awards awarded by these users with added date.

Its very critical. Is there a automated way to get this info?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/627594/9922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, Wikipedia records every individual edit to every page with a timestamp.

You'll probably only have to consider the "User talk" namespace, as the majority of barnstars are given by being posted on the awardee's talk page. And you can probably also ignore edits to IP users' talk pages and talk pages of editors with few edits, as those editors are unlikely to have received barnstars. It's also possible that you can identify from the edit summaries further edits to exclude. If you can identify only a few thousand revisions that actually need to be retrieved, you could probably get away with using the [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) to download those revisions; if there are many revisions, or you expect you might want a wider sample, you'd be better served to download a [database dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) and process the revisions offline.