# Mediawiki API: only search for human names

Tags: mediawiki-api

I want to get **all** human names in wiki titles within wikipedia using Mediawiki, and I am reading [Mediawiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search). I haven't found any keywords limiting category of the search (e.g. human names, countrie names, planet names, etc). Is it possible to do so by Mediawiki?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872326/api-to-retrieve-info-about-famous-people) question, but it is about using a name as input and see whether that is a person, which does not fit my requirement.

If it is not possible to do so, is there any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit search results to a category; it depends on the wiki what kind of categories they have. The search is not recursive (ie. if an article is in the category `African countries` and that category is in the category `Countries` and you limit search to that category, you won't find the article) which makes it not so useful in practice.

Specifically for Wikipedia, you have a number of non-standard options, most notably the [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/). E.g. [articles about people](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fsitelink%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%23%20humans%20only%0A%20%20%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20.%0A%20%20%0A%09%23%20look%20for%20articles%20%28sitelinks%29%20in%20English%0A%20%20%09%7B%20%3Fsitelink%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%20%3Fsitelink%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%3Fsitelink%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%2010).