# How to retrieve Wikipedia content into Android App?

Tags: android, rss, wikipedia

i want to make an android application, which gets latest updates from wikipedia website and displays it on android home screen using home widget. You can assume it something like weather widget. But, i am unfortunately unable to get updates from wikipedia. I just saw your thread regarding wikipedia, but I am still stuck in my problem.

Can you please send me any sample code, in which something is being brought from wikipedia into my android application. I would be very grateful to you. Please help me, i really need it....

Thanks

Regards,
Wajahat Karim
Android Developer,
Research Assistant (RA),
SMART Machines And Robotics Technology (SMART) Research Lab,
NUST School of Electrical Engineering & Computer Sciences (SEECS),
Islamabad Pakistan
Email: karim_nust@yahoo.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API, which lists the most recentchanges on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=recentchanges

Look at the base url for the help page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php