# Major cites in the world with latitude and longitude?

Tags: gps, location, latitude-longitude, city, geopositioning

I need a database of  major cities in this world, together with their latitude longitudes and timezone.  Is such a resource available?

any idea where i can get it. or any one can share it with me ?

Like this http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0001769.html

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What have you found out so far? What did the owner of that linked site tell you? Please, oh please, why do you want us to waste time on the same mistakes as you ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a structured API you can query to get info about a specific entry. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api) related question. [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_latitude) collects some of such resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would depend on what you class as a major city.

There's always the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) for obtaining Latitude, Longitude of places.

Answer (score 0):

You can find extensive worldwide geographic datasets on this [ftp](ftp://ftp.nga.mil/pub2/gns_data/) site. It's of military grade :-) believe me !