# Accessing main picture of wikipedia page by API

Tags: php, api, wikipedia-api

Is there any way I can access the thumbnail picture of any wikipedia page by using an API?  I mean the image on the top right side in box.  Is there any APIs for that?

Comment: All answers here are unreliable hacks that often give the wrong image. The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813352/how-to-reliably-get-the-image-used-in-the-wikipedia-infobox gives an image more often AND it is never the wrong image. I suggest merging the two questions.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Look at `prop=images`.

It returns an array of image filenames that are used in the parsed page. You then have the option of making another API call to find out the full image URL, e.g.:
`action=query&titles=Image:INSERT_EXAMPLE_FILE_NAME_HERE.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url`

or to [calculate the URL via the filename's hash](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_strangely_named_components_in_file_paths.3F).

Unfortunately, while the array of images returned by `prop=images` is in the order they are found on the page, the first can not be guaranteed to be the image in the info box because sometimes a page will include an image before the infobox (most of the time icons for metadata about the page: e.g. "this article is locked").

Searching the array of images for the first image that includes the page title is probably the best guess for the infobox image.

Comment: i can access images using prop, but its giving me multiple pictures http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=surfing&prop=images .  I dont know which one is main picture.

Comment: @Aby, I thinks this just a list of picture, you can not get the real image URL, so may be you can reference my anwser. and if you want to check the api document, see this `http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:FAQ`

Comment: Thanks for replying i checked out that image.

Comment: It's better to use the API call instead of calculating your own, because you still don't know if it's in Commons e.g. `/commons/a/ae/Filename.jpg` or language specific `/en/a/ae/Filename.jpg`

Comment: There is now a new property called pageimages, that filters out the default images.

Answer (score 75):

You can get the thumbnail of any wikipedia page using `prop=pageimages`. For example:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Al-Farabi&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=100
```

And you will get the thumbnail  full URL.

Comment: This is a great solution, but (for the record) it is based on a new-ish API extension that is marked 'experimental'.
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages

Comment: Maybe it's experimental, but it works! A second example, showing how to get thumbnails from multiple pages, in one single query: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=43273|990796&prop=pageimages&format=xml&pilimit=2

Comment: Is there a way to get this same information if you have the wikipedia (numeric) ID and not the wikipedia TITLE?

Comment: As I understand I need to know number 14533 that I could access image, but it changes all the time, so how can I open it? {"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"14533":{"pageid":14533,"ns":0,"title":"India","thumbnail":{"original":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg"}}}}}

Comment: @LaurynasG - You want to use formatversion=2 in your api call. `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages%7Cpageterms&titles=Albert%20Einstein`

Comment: Note that you also need to add `&pilicense=any` if you also want to get non-free thumbnail images (i.e., for things like video games, movies, etc.)

Answer (score 30):

This is good way to get the Main Image of a page in wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles=India

Comment: This answer is brief, but works! `pageimages` is probably new property, which is why it wasn't covered earlier, but gets the main image for the page.

Comment: Elegant ! The pageimages property was it. It The result is probably the first picture in the infobox template. And if you add images to the prop=, then you get all the other images on the page as well. (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|extracts|pageimages|images&inprop=url&pageids=14533)

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: Note that you also need to add `&pilicense=any` if you also want to get non-free thumbnail images (i.e., for things like video games, movies, etc.)

Answer (score 16):

Check out the MediaWiki API example for getting the main picture of a wikipedia page: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Page_info_in_search_results.

As other's have mentioned, you would use `prop=pageimages` in your API query.

If you also want the image description, you would use `prop=pageimages|pageterms` instead in your API query.

You can get the original image using `piprop=original`. Or you can get a thumbnail image with a specified width/height. For a thumbnail with width/height=600, `piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=600`. If you omit either, the image returned in the API callback will default to a thumbnail with width/height of 50px.

If you are requesting results in JSON format, you should always use `formatversion=2` in your API query (i.e., `format=json&formatversion=2`) because it makes retrieving the image from the query easier.

**Original Size Image:**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages|pageterms&piprop=original&titles=Albert Einstein
```

**Thumbnail Size (600px width/height) Image:**

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages|pageterms&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=600&titles=Albert Einstein
```

Comment: It's important to note that `pageimages` will not return the image url if wikipedia uses a non-free image. For instance, attempting to retrieve the image for Family Guy will not return an image: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages|pageterms&piprop=original&titles=Family%20Guy`

Comment: Note that you also need to add `&pilicense=any` if you also want to get non-free thumbnail images (i.e., for things like video games, movies, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Way 1: You can try some query like this:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=5&format=xml&search=italy&namespace=0

in the response, you can see the `Image` tag.

```
<Item>
<Text xml:space="preserve">Italy national rugby union team</Text>
<Description xml:space="preserve">
The Italy national rugby union team represent the nation of Italy in the sport of rugby union.
</Description>
<Url xml:space="preserve">
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italy_national_rugby_union_team
</Url>
<Image source="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/46/Italy_rugby.png/43px-Italy_rugby.png" width="43" height="50"/>
</Item>
```

Way 2:  use query http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=render&title=italy

then you can get a raw html code, you can get the image use something like `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser`
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

I have no time write it to you. just give you some advice, thanks.

Comment: This is a open search and this might give multiple pages on search..

Comment: @Aby, I have also studied `wiki api document` for a long time. so these 2 ways were what I thought it could be get the image. In my opinion, I'd like way 2, because if there have image on the page, you can easily get them out by `dom parse`. because all the wiki pages are generated by code, you can easily find the commons from them. they always lay in some `table` or `div` with `class aaa` or `class bbb`. that is all of my suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry for not answering specifically your question about the *main* image. But here's some code to get a list of all images:

```
function makeCall($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return curl_exec($curl);
}

function wikipediaImageUrls($url) {
    $imageUrls = array();
    $pathComponents = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
    $pageTitle = array_pop($pathComponents);
    $imagesQuery = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={$pageTitle}&prop=images&format=json";
    $jsonResponse = makeCall($imagesQuery);
    $response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
    $imagesKey = key($response['query']['pages']);
    foreach($response['query']['pages'][$imagesKey]['images'] as $imageArray) {
        if($imageArray['title'] != 'File:Commons-logo.svg' && $imageArray['title'] != 'File:P vip.svg') {
            $title = str_replace('File:', '', $imageArray['title']);
            $title = str_replace(' ', '_', $title);
            $imageUrlQuery = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:{$title}&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json";
            $jsonUrlQuery = makeCall($imageUrlQuery);
            $urlResponse = json_decode($jsonUrlQuery, true);
            $imageKey = key($urlResponse['query']['pages']);
            $imageUrls[] = $urlResponse['query']['pages'][$imageKey]['imageinfo'][0]['url'];
        }
    }
    return $imageUrls;
}
print_r(wikipediaImageUrls('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_%28mythology%29'));
print_r(wikipediaImageUrls('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-Ulrich_Rudel'));
```

I got this for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_%28mythology%29:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Arch_of_SeptimiusSeverus.jpg
    [1] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Ivan_Akimov_Saturn_.jpg
    [2] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Lucius_Appuleius_Saturninus.jpg
    [3] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Polidoro_da_Caravaggio_-_Saturnus-thumb.jpg
    [4] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Porta_Maggiore_Alatri.jpg
    [5] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/She-wolf_suckles_Romulus_and_Remus.jpg
    [6] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Throne_of_Saturn_Louvre_Ma1662.jpg
)
```

And for the second URL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-Ulrich_Rudel):

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/BmRKEL.jpg
    [1] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/BmRKELS.jpg
    [2] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Bundesarchiv_Bild_101I-655-5976-04%2C_Russland%2C_Sturzkampfbomber_Junkers_Ju_87_G.jpg
    [3] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Bundeswehr_Kreuz_Black.svg
    [4] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Flag_of_German_Reich_%281935%E2%80%931945%29.svg
    [5] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/64/HansUlrichRudel.jpeg
    [6] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Heinkel_He_111_during_the_Battle_of_Britain.jpg
    [7] => http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Regulation_WW_II_Underwing_Balkenkreuz.png
)
```

Note that the URL changed a bit on the 6th element of the second array. It's what @JosephJaber was warning about in his comment above.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: If anyone needs to actually see which object keys to reference to retrieve image from fetch response, THIS is the answer!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I have written some code that gets main image (full URL) by Wikipedia article title. It's not perfect, but overall I'm very pleased with the results.

The challenge was that when queried for a specific title, Wikipedia returns multiple image filenames (without path). Furthermore, the secondary search (I used the code varatis posted in this thread - thanks!) returns URLs of all images found based on the image filename that was searched, regardless of the original article title. After all this, we may end up with a generic image irrelevant to the search, so we filter those out. The code iterates over filenames and URLs until it finds (hopefully the best) match... a bit complicated, but it works :)

Note on the generic filter: I've been compiling a list of generic image strings for the isGeneric() function, but the list just keeps growing. I am considering maintaining it as a public list - if there is any interest let me know.

Pre:

```
protected static $baseurl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";
```

Main function - get image URL from title:

```
public static function getImageURL($title)
{
    $images = self::getImageFilenameObj($title); // returns JSON object
    if (!$images) return '';

    foreach ($images as $image)
    {
        // get object of image URL for given filename
        $imgjson = self::getFileURLObj($image->title);

        // return first image match
        foreach ($imgjson as $img)
        {
            // get URL for image
            $url = $img->imageinfo[0]->url;

            // no image found               
            if (!$url) continue;

            // filter generic images
            if (self::isGeneric($url)) continue;

            // match found
            return $url;
        }
    }
    // match not found
    return '';          
}
```

== The following functions are called by the main function above ==

Get JSON object (filenames) by title:

```
public static function getImageFilenameObj($title)
{
    try     // see if page has images
    {
        // get image file name
        $json = json_decode(
            self::retrieveInfo(
                self::$baseurl . '?action=query&titles=' .
                urlencode($title) . '&prop=images&format=json'
            ))->query->pages;

        /** The foreach is only to get around
         *  the fact that we don't have the id.
         */
        foreach ($json as $id) { return $id->images; }
    }
    catch(exception $e) // no images
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Get JSON object (URLs) by filename:

```
public static function getFileURLObj($filename)
{
    try                     // resolve URL from filename
    {
        return json_decode(
            self::retrieveInfo(
                self::$baseurl . '?action=query&titles=' .
                urlencode($filename) . '&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json'
            ))->query->pages;
    }
    catch(exception $e)     // no URLs
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Filter out generic images:

```
public static function isGeneric($url)
{
    $generic_strings = array(
        '_gray.svg',
        'icon',
        'Commons-logo.svg',
        'Ambox',
        'Text_document_with_red_question_mark.svg',
        'Question_book-new.svg',
        'Canadese_kano',
        'Wiki_letter_',
        'Edit-clear.svg',
        'WPanthroponymy',
        'Compass_rose_pale',
        'Us-actor.svg',
        'voting_box',
        'Crystal_',
        'transportation_inv',
        'arrow.svg',
        'Quill_and_ink-US.svg',
        'Decrease2.svg',
        'Rating-',
        'template',
        'Nuvola_apps_',
        'Mergefrom.svg',
        'Portal-',
        'Translation_to_',
        '/School.svg',
        'arrow',
        'Symbol_',
        'stub',
        'Unbalanced_scales.svg',
        '-logo.',
        'P_vip.svg',
        'Books-aj.svg_aj_ashton_01.svg',
        'Film',
        '/Gnome-',
        'cap.svg',
        'Missing',
        'silhouette',
        'Star_empty.svg',
        'Music_film_clapperboard.svg',
        'IPA_Unicode',
        'symbol',
        '_highlighting_',
        'pictogram',
        'Red_pog.svg',
        '_medal_with_cup',
        '_balloon',
        'Feature',
        'Aiga_'
    );

    foreach ($generic_strings as $str)
    {
        if (stripos($url, $str) !== false) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comments welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Lets take Example of Page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/index.html?curid=57570
to get Main Pic

Check out

> ### prop=pageprops
>
> **action=query&pageids=57570&prop=pageprops&format=json**

Results Page Data Eg.

```js
{ "pages" : { "57570":{
                    "pageid":57570,
                    "ns":0,
                    "title":"Sachin Tendulkar",
                    "pageprops" : {
                         "defaultsort":"Tendulkar,Sachin",
                         "page_image":"Sachin_at_Castrol_Golden_Spanner_Awards_(crop).jpg",
                         "wikibase_item":"Q9488"
                    }
            }
          }
 }}
```

We get main Pic file name this result as

> ** (wikiId).pageprops.page_image = Sachin_at_Castrol_Golden_Spanner_Awards_(crop).jpg**

Now as we have Image file name we will have to make another Api Call to get full image path from file name as follows

> **action=query&titles=Image:INSERT_EXAMPLE_FILE_NAME_HERE.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url**

Eg.

> action=query&titles=Image:Sachin_at_Castrol_Golden_Spanner_Awards_(crop).jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url

Returns Array of Image Data having url in it as 
**http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Sachin_at_Castrol_Golden_Spanner_Awards_%28crop%29.jpg**

Answer (score 3):

I there is a way to reliably get a main image for a wikipedia page - the Extension called PageImages

> The PageImages extension collects information about images used on a page.
>
> Its aim is to return the single most appropriate thumbnail associated
>   with an article, attempting to return only meaningful images, e.g. not
>   those from maintenance templates, stubs or flag icons. Currently it
>   uses the first non-meaningless image used in the page.

[https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPageImages)

Just add the prop pageimages to your API Query:

```
/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Somepage&format=xml
```

This reliably filters out annoying default images and prevents you from having to filter them yourself! The extension is installed on all the main wikipedia pages...

Answer (score 2):

Like Anuraj mentioned, the pageimages parameter is it. Look at the following url that'll bring about some nifty stuff:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|extracts|pageimages|images&inprop=url&exsentences=1&titles=india
```

Her are some interesting parameters:

- The two parameters *extracts* and *exsentences* gives you a short
  description you can use. (exsentences is the number of sentences you want to include in the excerpt)
- The info and the *inprop=url* parameters gives you the url of the page
- The prop property has multiple parameters separated by a bar symbol
- And if you insert the *format=json* in there, it is even better

Comment: As of 2023, this results in "Unrecognized parameters: exsentences, inprop"

Answer (score 1):

See [this related question on an API for Wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api). However, I would not know if it is possible to retrieve the thumbnail picture through an API.

You can also consider just parsing the web page to find the image URL, and retrieve the image that way.

Comment: thanks for replying, but fetching image on a wikipedia page is kind of impossible

Answer (score 1):

Here is my list of XPaths I have found work for 95 percent of articles. the main ones are 1, 2 3 and 4. A lot of articles are not formatted correctly and these would be edge cases:

You can use a DOM parsing lib to fetch image using the XPath.

```
static NSString   *kWikipediaImageXPath2    =   @"//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[1]/div/table/tr[2]/td/a/img";
static NSString   *kWikipediaImageXPath3    =   @"//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[1]/table/tr[1]/td/a/img";
static NSString   *kWikipediaImageXPath1    =   @"//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[1]/table/tr[2]/td/a/img";
static NSString   *kWikipediaImageXPath4    =   @"//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[2]/table/tr[2]/td/a/img";
static NSString   *kWikipediaImageXPath5    =   @"//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[1]/table/tr[2]/td/p/a/img";
static NSString   *kWikipediaImageXPath6    =   @"//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[1]/table/tr[2]/td/div/div/a/img";
static NSString   *kWikipediaImageXPath7    =   @"//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div[1]/table/tr[1]/td/div/div/a/img";
```

I used a ObjC wrapper called Hpple around libxml2.2 to pull out the image url. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cocoa Pod called **SDWebImage**

Code sample (remember to also add `import SDWebImage`):

```
func requestInfo(flowerName: String) {

        let parameters : [String:String] = [
            "format" : "json",
            "action" : "query",
            "prop" : "extracts|pageimages",//pageimages allows fetch imagePath
            "exintro" : "",
            "explaintext" : "",
            "titles" : flowerName,
            "indexpageids" : "",
            "redirects" : "1",
            "pithumbsize" : "500"//specify image size in px
        ]


        AF.request(wikipediaURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("Got the wikipedia info.")
                print(response)

                let flowerJSON : JSON = JSON(response.value!)
                let pageid = flowerJSON["query"]["pageids"][0].stringValue

                let flowerDescription = flowerJSON["query"]["pages"][pageid]["extract"].stringValue

                let flowerImageURL = flowerJSON["query"]["pages"][pageid]["thumbnail"]["source"].stringValue //fetching Image URL

                self.wikiInfoLabel.text = flowerDescription
                self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string : flowerImageURL))//imageView updated with Wiki Image

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think not, but you can capture the image using a link parser HTML documents

Comment: is there any way to access pictures using APIs?