# how to display images in array using php,if url is provided

Tags: php, json

,
how to display images in array using php,if url is provided..this is the full code i picked it from [Accessing main picture of wikipedia page by API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363531/accessing-main-picture-of-wikipedia-page-by-api)

```
<html>
<head></head><body><?php 
function makeCall($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return curl_exec($curl);
}

function wikipediaImageUrls($url) {
    $imageUrls = array();
    $pathComponents = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
    $pageTitle = array_pop($pathComponents);
    $imagesQuery = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={$pageTitle}&prop=images&format=json";
    $jsonResponse = makeCall($imagesQuery);
    $response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
    $imagesKey = key($response['query']['pages']);
    foreach($response['query']['pages'][$imagesKey]['images'] as $imageArray) {
        if($imageArray['title'] != 'File:Commons-logo.svg' && $imageArray['title'] != 'File:P vip.svg') {
            $title = str_replace('File:', '', $imageArray['title']);
            $title = str_replace(' ', '_', $title);
            $imageUrlQuery = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:{$title}&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json";
            $jsonUrlQuery = makeCall($imageUrlQuery);
            $urlResponse = json_decode($jsonUrlQuery, true);
            $imageKey = key($urlResponse['query']['pages']);
            $imageUrls[] = $urlResponse['query']['pages'][$imageKey]['imageinfo'][0]['url'];
        }
    }
    return $imageUrls;
?>
  for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  <img src="<?php echo $imageUrls[$i]; ?>" />
  <?php
}

print_r(wikipediaImageUrls('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_%28mythology%29'));
print_r(wikipediaImageUrls('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-Ulrich_Rudel'));

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with 2 modifications making it work the way you want:

```
<html>
<head></head><body><?php 
function makeCall($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return curl_exec($curl);
}

function wikipediaImageUrls($url) {
    $imageUrls = array();
    $pathComponents = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
    $pageTitle = array_pop($pathComponents);
    $imagesQuery = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={$pageTitle}&prop=images&format=json";
    $jsonResponse = makeCall($imagesQuery);
    $response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
    $imagesKey = key($response['query']['pages']);
    foreach($response['query']['pages'][$imagesKey]['images'] as $imageArray) {
        if($imageArray['title'] != 'File:Commons-logo.svg' && $imageArray['title'] != 'File:P vip.svg') {
            $title = str_replace('File:', '', $imageArray['title']);
            $title = str_replace(' ', '_', $title);
            $imageUrlQuery = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:{$title}&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json";
            $jsonUrlQuery = makeCall($imageUrlQuery);
            $urlResponse = json_decode($jsonUrlQuery, true);
            $imageKey = key($urlResponse['query']['pages']);
            $imageUrls[] = $urlResponse['query']['pages'][$imageKey]['imageinfo'][0]['url'];
        }
    }
    // return $imageUrls; /* 1st modif : do not return anything here */
    for($i=0; $i<count($imageUrls); $i++) {
        echo '<img src="'.$imageUrls[$i].'" />';
    }
}
/* 2nd modif : no print, just a call to your method because you already display stuff from the method */
wikipediaImageUrls('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_%28mythology%29');
wikipediaImageUrls('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-Ulrich_Rudel');

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let's say that's not what OP want's and this answer would be completely wrong!

Comment: Could be true, then hopefully the question will be completed with more info

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow. it is preventing me to add changes to code and i am not getting how to add the code.

Comment: Can't you edit the question? Otherwise try in a comment...

Comment: @AnilaMalik Maybe you want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: At least explain better what you want to achieve if this answer do not suit your needs...

Comment: i have tried with
>
  for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  <img src="<?php echo $imageUrls[$i]; ?>" />
  <?php
}

Comment: Edited my answer, with your code with a few modifications

Comment: Glad it helped. As you're new there, remember that you should check the answer as valid if it's what you were looking for.