# How to reliably get the image used in the Wikipedia Infobox?

Tags: json, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

How do I (reliably) get the main image(s) used in the Wikipedia Infobox from the API?

[This question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363531/accessing-main-picture-of-wikipedia-page-by-api) and the accepted answer admits that it is just a guess. Subsequent answers seem like a hack, at best and don't return the correct image.

For instance, the Jimi Hendrix Wikipedia entry uses `"File:Jimi Hendrix 1967.png"` as the main image in the InfoBox.

The updated answers suggest [using this url](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Jimi%20Hendrix&format=jsonfm) but for Jimi Hendrix (and other topics) it often returns the wrong image.

If I [pull in all the images](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Jimi+Hendrix&prop=images&format=jsonfm&imlimit=500) there is no way to determine which is the image used in the Infobox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Wikipedia page (e.g. [Jimi Hendrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimi_Hendrix)) is associated with an Wikidata item ID ([Q5928](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5928)). The main image for each Wikipedia article (usually this in the Infobox template) is kept by [image (P18)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P18) property in Wikidata, and you can access it by [MediaWiki Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&sites=enwiki&props=claims&titles=Jimi Hendrix
```

With this query you will get the Wikidata ID and the image name:

```
{
    ...
    "id": "Q5928", // Wikidata ID
    "claims":{
        ...
        "P18":[{
            "mainsnak":{
                "datavalue":{
                    "value":"Jimi Hendrix 1967.png", // The image name
                },
            },
        }],
        ...
    }
}
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393884/get-image-url-property-from-wikidata-api/34402875#34402875) I explain how to get the image URL also by using Wikidata ID.

Comment: I think that will work...thx! Is there anyway to return the first paragraph of the article w/ this query or do I need to do 2 queries? I'd like to make less API calls if possible.

Comment: WikiData is a repository for facts, so no, for that you'll have to query Wikipedia

Comment: @kristen, in this case it is better to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663229/how-to-get-a-short-snippet-of-text-and-the-main-image-of-wikipedia-articles-by-a

Comment: A lot of entries in wikidata do not provide the image. For example https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q588420 does not have the P18 property but it does have an image in the english wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_(film)

Comment: @GuillemPoy, this is because these images are not free and [copyrighted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Magnolia_poster.png).