# Wikipedia API Batch pageImages returning only first image

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to make a batch call to Wikipedia's query API to retrieve the `pageImages` (main image) and `extract`. For some reason my API call only returns an image for the first result, not the second:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=pageimages|extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow%7CMicrosoft&exlimit=2&pithumbsize=500&pilimit=2
```

This was happening with the extracts too, but it was solved by adding the `exlimit` parameter. Which as far as I understand, for `pageimages` the equivalent parameter is `pilimit`. Unfortunately this doesn't fix it.

How can I change the API call above to return a batch collection of Wikipedia results, with each result having an `extract` and `pageImages`?

Comment: The StackOverflow article does not have a page image, that's all.

Comment: Which was what I found confusing because it seems to have a 'main image' on its Wikipedia page, but its just that its not labelled as the `pageImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is probably a bug with `pageimages`, so you can use [`images`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bimages) instead. Second, the images for the second title will be displayed only after all images for the first title are displayed. etc., so you need to use `imlimit=max`:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=images|extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow|Microsoft&exlimit=2&imlimit=max
```

Comment: I'm glad you agree that there could be a bug! I thought there was something wrong with my implementation. Do you have any suggestions of how to find the main image from the images? Thank you!

Comment: Hm, for the main image it is better to use `pageimages` because `images` sort them, but you have to decide do you need all images or only the main. Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663229/how-to-get-a-short-snippet-of-text-and-the-main-image-of-wikipedia-articles-by-a

Comment: WOW, imlimit=max is exactly what I needed. Most answers in other threads dont highlight this enough as I have overlooked this countless times. I was getting like 50 'continue' requests. and almost gave up. This fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Add `pilicense=any` if you want to get non-free images as well ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=pageimages|extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow%7CMicrosoft&exlimit=2&pithumbsize=500&pilimit=2&pilicense=any), [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=pageimages%7Cextracts&titles=Microsoft%7CStack+Overflow&pithumbsize=500&pilimit=max&pilicense=any&exlimit=max&exintro=1&explaintext=1)). Due to various limitations on how they can be used, these tend to be not so great (e.g. lower resolution).

Comment: Thanks! It worked, it returns the exact image I was expecting and previously lacking.