# Any way to load contents from wikipedia to my site?

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Wikipedia API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api)

Is there any API or any particular way to load pages to my site. For example if am viewing www.mysite.com/php , its should display a block which contains data from wiki!

Please give a sample example too

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i cant find any api yet!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [the documentation for the Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) shows up very near the top of a Google [search for Wikipedia API](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wikipedia+api).

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has an API, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

You can use this for loading contents, though be careful not to simply 'data mine' from Wikipedia as this will score your sites negatively in search engines.

Comment: I just want a block which will show as additional info .. Thanks

Comment: can you give a basic sample? for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox which action returns contents of a particular page?

Comment: I imagine you're looking at `prop=extracts` or similar, you need to look at what you need and therefore which part of articles you wish to request.