# How to setup wiki for emergency response?

Tags: structure, wiki, mission-critical

Company I work for is currently preparing to expand and take on emergency support (after hours support).

We currently have a wiki setup with a lot of information. 
However, due to the fact that bits and pieces are scattered across entire wiki (dependable on what department etc).

Whoever is on support that night/weekend needs to quickly be able to help customer with their problems. eg. if our server is being very slow there needs to be troubleshooting guide of some sort so that person can dig straight into it.

I have googled quite a bit but I was not able to find anything useful. So here is a question:

*How would you structure your wiki (by topic, by symptoms, by solutions?) to minimize time person has to look for information?*
Personally, I think using some sort of syntax such as

```
Symptom: large CPU utilization 

Keywords: slow server, large cpu usage
```

That way when you search through wiki it would most likely come up in search. But what if issue is more software related - such as miss-configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This is wiki API url
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Also you need to have a Web Service which will accept the params on which search will be performed as well as UI page.

Web Service will have all the logics which ever needed.

[Is there a Wikipedia API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api)