# Best method to scrape large number of Wikipedia tables to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, screen-scraping, wikipedia

What would be the best programmatic way to grab all the HTML tables of Wikipedia main article pages where the pages' titles match certain keywords? Then I would like to take the column names and table data and put them into a database.

Would also grab the URL and page name for attribution.

I don't need specifics just some recommended methods or links to some tutorials perhaps.

Comment: Rather than scraping, wouldn't you be better off using the api (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page). See also... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api

Comment: Yup. Sorry, I was using scraping as a general catch-all word. I have looked into the API.

Comment: Any particular programming language you will be using?

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach to this is not to scrape the wikipedia website at all. All of the data, metadata, and associated media that form Wikipedia are available in structured formats; so preclude any need to scrape their web pages.

To get the data from Wikipedia into your database (which you may then search, slice and dice 'til your heart's content):

1. Download the [data files](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps).
2. Run the [SQLize tool](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Tools_for_importing) of your choice
3. Run mysqlimport
4. Drink a coffee.

The URL of the original article should be able to be re-constructed from the page title pretty easily.

Comment: Can anyone add more detail on detecting the HTML tables then converting those into SQL?