# How to extract data between two nodes in a wiki page with JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, mediawiki-api, wiktionary

```
Document doc = getDocumen("https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/set#set_.28j.C4.99zyk_angielski.29");
Elements links = doc.select("dfn[style]"); - ??
for (Element link : links)
{
  link.select("a [href]");
  String linkText = link.text()
}
```

- I want to get from "set (język angielski)", all meanings (znaczenia:
  )
- The result should be a pair:

  ```
    rzeczownik - (1.1) zestaw
    rzeczownik - (1.2) mat. zbiór (lub bez nawiasów)
    ...
    przymiotnik - (2.1) gotowy
    ...
  ```

Comment: You can use parser to get what you want. Take a look at this link - http://jsoup.org/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Wikipedia API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why were you unsatisfied with those outcomes?

Comment: I have access only to the first section "set (język polski)" .
I don't know how to navigate between sections and read them meanings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would try it:

```
Document doc = getDocumen("https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/set#set_.28j.C4.99zyk_angielski.29");
Elements elements = doc.select("h2:has(span#en) ~ p:not(h2:has(span#en) ~ p ~ h2 ~ p) i, h2:has(span#en) ~ p:not(h2:has(span#en) ~ p ~ h2 ~ p) + dl > dd");
if (elements.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("No definitions found.");
}

String parent = null;
for (Element element : elements) {
    switch (element.tagName().toLowerCase()) {
    case "i":
        parent = element.text();
        break;

    case "dd":
        System.out.println(parent + " - " + element.text());
        break;

    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected element:\n" + element.outerHtml());
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
rzeczownik - (1.1) zestaw
rzeczownik - (1.2) mat. zbiór
rzeczownik - (1.3) elektron. odbiornik, aparat odbiorczy
rzeczownik - (1.4) film. plan zdjęciowy
rzeczownik - (1.5) sport. set
rzeczownik - (1.6) teatr. dekoracja
rzeczownik - (1.7) tendencja, kierunek
rzeczownik - (1.8) koteria
rzeczownik - (1.9) nora borsuka
rzeczownik - (1.10) masz. agregat
przymiotnik - (2.1) gotowy
przymiotnik - (2.2) stały, ustalony
przymiotnik - (2.3) nieruchomy
przymiotnik - (2.4) postanowiony
przymiotnik - (2.5) określony
czasownik - (3.1) układać, ustawiać
czasownik - (3.2) nastawiać (kość)
czasownik - (3.3) prostować
czasownik - (3.4) przygotowywać
czasownik - (3.5) powodować
czasownik - (3.6) o słońcu: zachodzić
czasownik - (3.7) ustalać
```

IMO, you should try to find a wiki API. Although the data seems to share the same presentation from page to page, the html code behind it may vary.

**DISCUSSION**

The key of the above code is the CSS query.

```
h2:has(span#en) ~ p:not(h2:has(span#en) ~ p ~ h2 ~ p) i, h2:has(span#en) ~ p:not(h2:has(span#en) ~ p ~ h2 ~ p) + dl > dd
```

This query selects `p` nodes between two `h2` nodes. In order to achieve this goal, here how to do it:

```
h2:has(span#en) /* Select the h2 node having the span with id 'en' */
~ p /* Select all p nodes preceded by previous selected h2 node... */
:not(h2:has(span#en) ~ p ~ h2 ~ p) /* ... but ignore any p nodes after the previously selected p nodes */
```

**Tested on JSoup 1.8.3**

**EDIT:**
OP has suggested [JWBF](https://github.com/eldur/jwbf) (Java Wiki Bot Framework) as a wiki API.

Comment: I got "No definitions found" :(

Comment: About wiki Api. I tried jwbf and i don't know how to do with api

Comment: @user2721692 Which url gave you "No definitions found"?

Comment: @user2721692 Stick with Jsoup for now and let jwbf be used for edge cases.

Comment: @user2721692 Actually, when the page is loaded, some javascript is executed. I rebuild de CSS query to work on the html code **before** this javascript execution. I have updated my code accordingly.