# Is it possible to get place information like Google maps show using GoogleMaps iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sdk, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have GMSPlace object, but in iOS SKD so small information, it's killing me!

Is it possible use another library, not only Google to get information about some address with detail information - some like historical help.

For example i want get information like google map do

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of information what you are looking can be extracted from the [Google Places services](https://developers.google.com/places/) called “Place Detail”. To get most of this information you need to have **placeid**. One way to get **placeid** is to do “Place Search”. Supported types is [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

As well in your screenshot I see reference to the wikipedia. Wikipedia have its own [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php). Question was asked about it some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api).

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramis answered, You should check the "Place Detail" of "Google Places services"

There's a public API to get Detail information by passing PlaceID:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=#{PLACE_ID_FROM_GOOGLE_PLACES}&key=#{YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The documentation is here: [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/)

I have tested this with Google Maps SDK for iOS version 1.10, the Demo has a places list, each place has a `placeID`, you can get detail by passing it to the link above.

But I don't know Google Places services will output something relative to Wikipedia or not.