# CLISP open-http example

Tags: http, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to read a series of web pages with CLISP, if they exist, but I don't understand how [open-http](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes.html#open-http) works to skip non existing web pages.
I have the following:

```
(dolist (word '(a b c))
  (with-open-stream (stream (ext:open-http
                              (format nil
                                      "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/~a.html"
                                      word)
                              :if-does-not-exist nil))
    (when stream
      (print word))))
```

I want to simply skip a web-page if it doesn't exist, but CLISP seems to hang and returns an "Invalid argument" error.
Could anyone explain how the argument :if-does-not-exist works and/or provide examples of how to use open-http. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are going to have problems with other things in the process: almost all websites use HTTPS nowadays, CLISP's `OPEN-HTTP` doesn't support HTTPS. Also, as far as I can see, Wikipedia's articles are not placed in *.html files, and other files have more complicated paths.

Comment: Related: [Is there a Wikipedia API?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/627594/124319). Also, have a look at [Drakma](http://weitz.de/drakma/)

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far, but please focus on the question: how do you prevent open-http from hanging when the page does not exist, irrespective of its url. An example would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It does work for me:

```
(with-open-stream (stream (ext:open-http
                           "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234242424242"
                           :if-does-not-exist nil))
(format t "~&Stream: ~A~%" stream))
```

Output:

```
;; connecting to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234242424242"...connected...HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
;; HTML source of Page not found
Stream: NIL
NIL
```

There is a delay to get the connection, but it works.

If the page does exist:

```
[7]> (with-open-stream (stream (ext:open-http
                                "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003343/clisp-open-http-example"
                                :if-does-not-exist nil))
       (format t "~&Stream: ~A~%" stream))
;; connecting to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003343/clisp-open-http-example"...connected...HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Stream: #<IO INPUT-BUFFERED SOCKET-STREAM CHARACTER stackoverflow.com:80>
NIL
```

With Wikipedia I couldn't make it work since Wikipedia.org re-directs it to HTTPS and `EXT:OPEN-HTTP` neither can handle HTTPS directly, nor it can handle redirects:

Here if HTTPS is used directly:

```
[10]> (with-open-stream (stream (ext:open-http
                                 "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp"
                                 :if-does-not-exist nil))
        (format t "~&Stream: ~A~%" stream))

*** - OPEN-HTTP: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp" is not an HTTP URL
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [11]> :r1
```

If "https" is replaced by "http", CLISP doesn't construct a proper address:

```
[12]> (with-open-stream (stream (ext:open-http
                                 "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp"
                                 :if-does-not-exist nil))
        (format t "~&Stream: ~A~%" stream))
;; connecting to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp"...connected...HTTP/1.1 301 TLS Redirect --> "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp"
;; connecting to "http://en.wikipedia.orghttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp"...
*** - PARSE-INTEGER: substring "" does not have integer syntax at position 0
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [13]>
```