# How do I scrape link of only one column from a Wikipedia table with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I'm a beginner and this is my first question on the forum.
As said in the title, my goal is to scrape the links from only one column of the table of that wiki page : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_de_l%27Ain

I've already watched several contributions asked on that forum (especially this one [How do I extract text data in first column from Wikipedia table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909574/how-do-i-extract-text-data-in-first-column-from-wikipedia-table))  but none of them seem to answer my questions (and from what I understand, using a Dataframe is not a solution since it is a sort of copy/paste of the table while I want to get links).

Here is my code so far

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_de_l%27Ain")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup=bs(res.text,"html.parser")
table=soup.find('table','wikitable')
links=table.findAll('a')
communes={}
for link in links:
    url=link.get("href","")
    communes[link.text.strip()]=url
print(communes)
```

Thanks in advance for you answers !

Comment: What column specifically do you want to scrape?

Comment: only the first column to get the links of the cities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape a specific column, you can use the [`nth-of-type(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS Selector. In order to use a CSS Selector, use the [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all).

For example, to only scrape the sixth column, select the sixth `<td>` using `soup.select("td:nth-of-type(6)")`

Here's an example of how to print all the links from only the fifth column:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


BASE_URL = "https://fr.wikipedia.org"
URL = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_de_l%27Ain"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

# The following will find all `a` tags under the fifth `td` of it's type, which is the fifth column
for tag in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(5) a"):
    print(BASE_URL + tag["href"])
```

Output:

```
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_de_Bourg-en-Bresse-1
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_de_Bourg-en-Bresse-2
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_d%27Amb%C3%A9rieu-en-Bugey
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_de_Villars-les-Dombes
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_de_Belley
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer is very useful !

Comment: I clicked one up to say that "your answer is useful" but it doesn't count yet since I'm less than 15 in reputation

Comment: @AnthonySULIO Just click on the checkmark near this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first column, containing the communes, you can also use the fact it is left aligned in an attribute = value selector

```
commune_links = ['https://fr.wikipedia.org' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[style="text-align:left;"] a')]
```

Comment: And do you know why it works with this link https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_de_l%27Ain
and not this one https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_du_Pas-de-Calais ?

Comment: For that one you need to specify the table as well `commune_links = ['https://fr.wikipedia.org' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.titre-en-couleur [style="text-align:left;"] a')]`

Comment: Hi @QHarr I have another question. Do you know why i can get all the links with `commune_links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('.titre-en-couleur a')]`
but I can't get the number of the population with 
`commune_links = [i['data-sort-value'] for i in soup.select('.titre-en-couleur td')]`

Comment: you need `soup.select(".titre-en-couleur td[data-sort-value]")`