# How to hold a reference to the items matched by `querySelectorAll`, in a variable, that allows you to access its methods?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, mshtml, selectors-api, nodelist

**Intro:**

Some of you may have noticed that something has broken in relation to the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method of `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` from `MSHTML.Dll` (via a `Microsoft HTML Document Library` reference). This, I believe, has happened in the last month. It may not affect all users and I will update this Q&A as I get more info on which versions etc are affected. Please feel free to comment below with your set-up and whether working or not for both late-bound and early-bound (as per code in answer)

---

**Accessing `DispStaticNodeList` methods:**

Traditionally, at least in my experience, it has been the norm to hold a reference to the `DispStaticNodeList`, which is what `querySelectorAll` returns, in a generic late-bound [`Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-data-type) type:

E.g.

```
Dim nodeList1 As Object

Set nodeList1 = html.querySelectorAll("a")
```

where `html` is an instance of `MSHTML.HTMLDocument`.

As you can see from the Locals window, you get the expected `nodeList` shown:

[image]

You could then access the list of the document's elements, that match the specified group of selectors, with `.item(index)`, and get the number of items matched with `.Length`. E.g.

```
Debug.Print nodeList1.item(0).innerText
Debug.Print nodeList1.Length
```

---

**What happens now?**

Attempts to access the methods, via late bound `Object`, and its underlying interfaces, lead to either an `Object required`, when using the `.item()` method call, or `Null` when querying the `.Length()`. E.g.

```
nodeList1.item(0).innertext  ' => Run-time error '424': Object required
Debug.Print nodeList1.Length ' => Null
```

This happens when you hold a reference through assigning to a variable.

---

**What you can do:**

You can use `With` and work off `html`, avoiding the `Object` class

```
With html.querySelectorAll("a")
    For i = 0 To .Length - 1
       Debug.Print .Item(i).innerText
    Next
End With
```

So, I think the problem is very much about the `Object` data type and its underlying interfaces. And possibly, something about this has broken in relation to MSHTML, and most likely, the now no longer supported, Internet Explorer, which sits in the background:

[image]

However, this is not desirable, as you parse, and re-parse, the same HTML, during the loop, losing much of the efficiency that its gained by choosing css selectors over traditional methods e.g. `getElementsByClassName`. Those traditional methods remain intact.

---

**Why do some of us care?**

Modern browsers (and even IE8 onwards) support faster node matching through use of css selectors. It seems reasonable to assume that this carried over into the DOM parsers with `MSHTML.HTMLDocument`. So, you have faster matching, combined with more expressive and concise syntax (none of those long chained method calls e.g. `getElementsByClassName("abc")(0).getElementsByTagName("def")(0).....`), the ability to return more desired nodes, without repeated calls (in the prior example you will only get `def` as children of the first element with class `abc`, rather than all children, with tag `def`, of all elements with class `abc`, which you would get with `querySelectorAll(".abc def")`. And, you lose the flexibility to specify much more complex and specific patterns for node matching e.g. `querySelectorAll(".abc > def + #ghi)`. For those interested, you can read more about those selectors on [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

---

**Question:**

So, how does one avoid re-parsing, and hold the reference to the returned list of matched nodes? I have found nothing on the internet, despite quite a bit of searching, that documents this recent change in behaviour. It is also a very recent change and that likely only affects a small user base.

I hope the above satisfies the need to demonstrate research into the problem.

---

**My set-up:**

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042
System Type x64-based PC
Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (16.0.13929.20206) 32-bit (Microsoft Office Professional Plus)
Version 2104 Build 13929.20373
mshtml.dll info as per image
```

---

**Not affected (TBD):**

1. Office Professional plus 2013. Win 7, 32 bit, MSHTML.dll 11.0.9600.19597

Comment: Hi @QHarr, I suppose you wanna give [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613429/got-results-in-one-pc-but-encountered-run-time-error-438-in-another-pc-even-wh) a go as the issue in there is somewhat related to what you have discussed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not despair VBA web-scrapers (I know there are a few!) We can still have the luxury of css selectors and the benefits, though admittedly somewhat limited in VBA, that they bring.

**To the rescue:**

`MSHTML`, *gratias* IE,  offers a number of [scripting object interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/hh801967(v=vs.85)) . One of which is the [`IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection`](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752483(v=vs.85)) interface, which inherits from [`IDispatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and which:

> provides methods to access items in the collection.

This includes the `.Length` property and access to items via `.item(index)`.

```
Dim nodeList2 As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection

Set nodeList2 = html.querySelectorAll("a")
Debug.Print nodeList2.Length                 ' => n 
Debug.Print nodeList2.Item(0).innerText
```

This is supported on clients Windows XP +, and servers from Windows 2000 Server onwards.

---

**VBA:**

```
Public Sub ReviewingNodeListMethods()
    '' References (VBE > Tools > References):
          ''Microsoft HTML object Library
          ''Microsoft XML library (v.6 for me)

    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument   'XMLHTTP60 is for Excel 2016. Change according to your version e.g. XMLHTTP for 2013)
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://books.toscrape.com/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim nodeList1 As Object, nodeList2 As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    
    Set nodeList1 = html.querySelectorAll("a")
    Set nodeList2 = html.querySelectorAll("a")
  
    Debug.Print nodeList1.Length                 ' => Null
    Debug.Print nodeList2.Length                 ' => 94
    
    Debug.Print nodeList2.Item(0).innerText
    
    '    Dim i As Long
    '
    '    With html.querySelectorAll("a")
    '        For i = 0 To .Length - 1
    '           Debug.Print .Item(i).innerText
    '        Next
    '    End With
    
    '' ================Warning: This will crash Excel -============================

    '    Dim node As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMNode
    '
    '    For Each node In nodeList2
    '        Debug.Print node.innerText
    '    Next
    '' ================Warning: This will crash Excel -============================

End Sub
```

---

**N.B.** There is still the [underlying problem of the collection enumeration method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021133/excel-crashes-when-attempting-to-inspect-dispstaticnodelist); it causes Excel to crash if you attempt a `For Each` e.g.

```
Dim node As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMNode

For Each node In nodeList2
    Debug.Print node.innerText
Next
```

---

**Updating your old Questions/Answers:**

1. You can use this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1410429/1733716/search-with-partials) to identify potential candidates for revision. Enter your userid and the search term "querySelectorAll"
2. Or simply use the following in the search bar:
   `querySelectorAll user:<userid> is:answer` ; `querySelectorAll user:<userid> is:question`

Comment: I get 94 from either of the node list.

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide me with some version/system info please? It would be helpful to document.

Comment: Excel version: Office Professional plus 2013. Win 7, 32 bit.

Comment: thank you for that. What is your mshtml.dll install please?  It will be in a folder under C:\Windows\  e.g.  for me it is within `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: I didn't get any notification of your last text, so I would never know that you asked something unless I visit this page. However, [is this](https://imgur.com/w7c3XGC) what you wanted to know @QHarr?

Comment: @SIM You around please to help me with some testing?

Comment: I was not around. I'll be available within few minutes @QHarr.

Comment: @SIM Hello. Join me in the [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus-) and ping me when free please.

Comment: Why don't I see any option in the chat room to send you any text @QHarr?

Comment: I don't know. One moment. You are not showing as in the room at all. @SIM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233062/discussion-between-qharr-and-sim).

Comment: I think we can create a script which will run in all version of excel if we avoid using nextsibling. Please give [this](https://pastebin.com/1Xw9FKwU) a shot if you have time. If you get success, I'm sure that will be a workaround @QHarr.

Comment: Hello there @SIM \o

Comment: Hi @QHarr, hope you are doing fine.

Comment: I like this `[A1:C1] = [{"Product Id"," Land Size","Total Main Area"}]
`

Comment: Your linked code fails here: `Cells(R, 2) = " " & .Item(I).ParentNode.ParentNode.LastChild.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText`

Comment: Mathieu Guindon will berate you if he comes across your comment. He doesn't like that style at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233856/discussion-between-qharr-and-sim).