# Got results in one pc but encountered `Run-time error 438` in another pc even when I used the same script

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've created a script to parse `recipe` name and `serving` from such [links](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/18871/easy-tuna-casserole/). When I run the same script in two different computers, I get expected results in one computer but I encounter this error ***Run-time error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method)*** in another computer. The script throws that error pointing at this line `Servings = .Item(I).NextSibling.innerText` within the script below.

The excel version, OS and bit  `Excel 2019, windows 10, 64bit` of that pc which `errors out`.

The excel version, OS and bit  `Excel 2013, windows 7, 32bit` of that pc which `finds success`.

This is the script that I used :

```
Public Sub FetchRecipeInfo()
    Dim Http As Object, Html As HTMLDocument, Servings$, R&
    Dim Url As Variant, linkList As Variant, I&, Ws As Worksheet
    
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    R = 1

    linkList = Array( _
        "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/18871/easy-tuna-casserole/", _
        "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/21791/tuna-noodle-casserole-iv/" _
       )

    For Each Url In linkList
        With Http
            .Open "GET", Url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        
        Ws.Cells(R, 1) = Html.querySelector("h1.headline").innerText

        With Html.querySelectorAll(".recipe-meta-item-header")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                If InStr(.item(I).innerText, "Servings:") > 0 Then
                    Servings = .item(I).NextSibling.innerText
                    Ws.Cells(R, 2) = Servings
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next I
        End With
        R = R + 1
    Next Url
End Sub
```

Expected output:

```
Easy Tuna Casserole 8
```

> Why I get results in one pc but encounter `Run-time error 438` in another pc even when I use the same script?

Comment: Maybe another PC does not have Mozilla version update, therefore your xml parse is in different format or empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it works on another machine. I assume something to do with the underlying parsers. With my set-up (Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (16.0.13929.20206) 32-bit Windows 10 MSHTML.dll 11.00.19041.985), there is a text node as immediate adjacent sibling which doesn't have a `.innerText` property, but rather you could use `.nodeValue`. Instead, I think you wanted to move on to the next sibling i.e.

```
Servings = .Item(I).NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText
```

That works on Windows 10 64 bit. So, if this new line fails on your Win 7 then wrap in an If Else based on version.

Comment: It works `.item(I).NextSibling.innerText` in excel 2013 but fails when I try this `.Item(I).NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText`.

Comment: Wrap in an If Else I guess based on version. What is different, it seems, it the presence/absence of the intermediate text node / it's handling within the parser.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: Try printing out item(n).outerHTML on both machines and compare.

Comment: This is `<DIV class=recipe-meta-item-body>8 </DIV>` what I get in `Excel 2013` . Unfortunately, I'm not around that pc in which `Excel 2019` is installed, so I could not test the other one.

Comment: If I'm not wrong it's happening just because of the excel version, not because of the OS version.

Comment: yes it runs except, I have to change from Object type in Set ingrContainer

Comment: I also meant the parent div of those two divs

Comment: What should I set the object type of `ingrContainer` to make it work in 2019?

Comment: I had to `Dim As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection` ;any variable that holds a nodelist returned by querySelectorAll. You have another var like this.

Comment: So defining that object type `MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection` for `ingrContainer` worked for you in 2019, right? I'm deeply sorry to ask you too many questions. I wanted to install that office version in my windows but win 7 doesn't support that.

Comment: Thanks a trillion for your great support. This thing `MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection` was totally foreign to me until you created your own post on it..