# Will IE removal from Windows impact XMLHTTP60?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

When IE gets removed from Windows, will this impact XMLHTTP60 and my Excel VBA code? How could one confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: MSXML6 is available within Edge. As MS don't release technical implementation details I cannot comment on whether there will be any of the changes similar to those I saw with MSHTML. I haven't noticed any to date (either directly or via online posts such as on SO).

Undocumented MSHTML changes did break some code, but that all happened some time ago, and I made reference to some of those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759228/what-are-the-currently-supported-css-selectors-available-to-vba) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67596872/how-to-hold-a-reference-to-the-items-matched-by-queryselectorall-in-a-variabl), where I think MSHTML was being "upgraded/uncoupled" in the background as it was tied to Internet Explorer as a product. The wider use of MSXML means, I think (non-expert), we are less likely to see breaking changes.

MSXML Core Services is widely used across [a range of products](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/previous-versions/troubleshoot/msxml/list-of-xml-parser-versions) and is actively maintained. It's maintenance depends on the [OS support lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/jj152146(v=vs.85)).

MSXML6 is [the only version of MSXML implemented in Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-xml/6237a4fd-0bd8-4451-952c-8b1b3f03bbe5), which uses it only to implement XSLT [W3C-XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116).

Underlying implementation details are not released due Microsoft's Security Policy. You could ask about specific observed behaviour within one of their [Q&A platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/)

Slightly worried this verges into opinion territory. Have added links above that hopefully are useful.