# How to search a particular website from a flutter app

Tags: flutter

i need to search wikipedia or amazon from my flutter app for a given keyword. For example, if somebody enters iphone, i can call amazon and show results in my app. When they click on the returned result, amazon is launched.

Please suggest how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use API from Amazon and Wikipedia. For Amazon You can Use this [API](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/search-items.html). For Wikipedia [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api) might be helpful.

If you want to directly Open search Result(Like Search Box =>User Type in Search Box => open amazon for search result) then you can use something like this.

As Per URL of Search Result

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=iphone

so create Url Like

```
    getResult(String Keyword){
    
    String url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k =$keyword"
    print(url)
      return url
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to get that website API that is if it's available, you can only do that with there API

Comment: You can also use a web scraper to scrape HTML elements from a web page. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `web_scraper` to do the web scraping after you issue an HTTP GET call to the query URL.

[web_scraper 0.1.4](https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper)